Добавление бина SessionFactory сломало проект
Мне нужно было сделать пустой проект с Hibernate, Spring и Lombok. Я его сделал, но решил поэкспериментировать, добавляя какую-то логику.
После добавления бина для SessionFactory проект перестал запускаться с ошибкой

Description: A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found. Action: Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело?
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>VTBInnotehDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>VTBInnotehDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for VTB Innoteh</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return buildSessionFactory(Person.class, Phone.class);
    }
    private SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(Class<?> ...annotatedClasses) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(createServiceRegistry(configuration));
        Arrays.stream(annotatedClasses).forEach(metadataSources::addAnnotatedClass);
        Metadata metadata = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
        return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    }
    private StandardServiceRegistry createServiceRegistry(Configuration configuration){
        return new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    }
}


Проблема решена. В классе MyConfig изменил @Bean на @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory"), после этого ошибка ушла.
